# Web API Returns the Zip Folder / File

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

There is a WebAPI which returns the ZIP FOLDER. Which directly gets downloaded if i click or go to this below URL on browser:

WEB API URL :

http://54.186.6.13:81/api/DownloadAPI/DownloadTranslatedFile?projectid=17&fileid=

How can I download the ZIP FILE / FOLDER using `C#.net`?

My C#.net Code for Calling the WEB API:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var responseT = client.GetAsync(XMLPath).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
                {
                    if (responseT.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                      // HOW I DOWNLOAD THE ZIP FILE, WHICH IS RETURNED BY 
                         THE ABOVE WEB API
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try the following:

```
FileStream file = await (FileStream)responseT.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var copyToFile = File.Create("C:\\path\\to\\where\\you\\want\\the\\file.zip");
await file.CopyToAsync(copyToFile);
```

Comment: That should probably be `await file.CopyToAsync(copyToFile);`.  You should probably also be awaiting `ReadAsStreamAsync` as well.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've added your suggestions